# Is there a way to assign 'Default Role' in bulk in BIM 360?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'd like to assign a default role to all users in BIM 360 who do not have one assigned yet.

Looking through the Forge Documentation, I haven't found the "Default Role" field represented in the Forge API. Is there a way to modify it through the Forge API? If not, is there another way to modify this field in bulk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding users to the hub, the "default_role" parameter defines the user's default role in the account.
You can specify it by adding the "default_role" field when calling [POST users/import](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-import-POST/) endpoint.
You should specify in this field a valid name of an industry role available.
One example of a valid call to add a user with default role would contain the body below:

```
[{
  "email": "user email",
  "default_role":"some valid role name",
  "default_role_id": "some valid role id"
}]
```

From there, when you add the user to a project from UI, it'll come with this role defined.

When you add to a project from API, the "industry_roles" parameter will define their roles (reference [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/#body-structure)).

Comment: The default_role parameter is the focus of the question - I have not found it on any existing endpoint. The industry_role endpoint you link sets the role for a given project, not the default_role, which is at the account level.

Comment: There is also no mention of adding a user to a project, authentication, or 2-legged tokens in the question asked. This information isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: My apologies for any confusion, @eisaac. I edited my answer with more details specifically about default_role. If anything is still unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Perfectly clear now, thank you João!